# How to import module in express api

Tags: node.js, api, express, ecmascript-6, module

I want to connect Elasticsearch to my express rest API by writing a small module of connection :

**db.connection.js**

```
import { Client } from 'elasticsearch'
const client = new Client({
    hosts: ['http://localhost:9200']
});
client.ping({
    requestTimeout: 30000,
}, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.error('Elasticsearch cluster is down!');
    } else {
        console.log('Everything is ok');
    }
});

module.exports = Client;
```

when trying to import the module in my app.js the server return ***Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module***

***app.js***

```
import http from 'http'
import express from 'express'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import json from 'express'
import helmet from 'helmet'
import cors from 'cors'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import connection from './config/db.connection'
const app = express();


// allow cors requests from any origin and with credentials
app.use(cors({ origin: (origin, callback) => callback(null, true), credentials: true }));
// set security HTTP headers
app.use(helmet())
// parse json request body
app.use(json())
// logger
app.use(morgan('dev'))
// parses cookies attached to the client request object
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(dotenv.config)

// start server
const port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? (process.env.PORT || 80) : 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});

connection.cluster.health({}, function (err, resp, status) {
    console.log("-- Client Health --", resp);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.send({ project: 'fwinr' })
});
```

I added '  "type": "module" in package.js but it doesn't works, how to fix that

Comment: You're trying to import connection from db.connection.js, but there you export Client. Maybe there's your issue

Comment: I changed it , some error

Comment: Is your problem gone now?

Comment: On which file system paths are these files located?

Comment: @mlod_ no same error

Comment: @Bergi the project located in the home path of ubuntu OS, the files app.js is in the root of project folder and db.connection.js in config folder